# How to set a custom Gem path in RubyMine 2018.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, configuration, rubygems, rubymine

I have been running RubyMine 2017.2 with a batch script that sets the GEM_HOME environment variable (along with others) and then runs the program. This had been working, RubyMine sees the path and I can see it listed as the installation and executable directories when I do Tools - Show Gem Environment.

I just upgraded to version 2018.2 and changed my batch script to point to the new version. I did not change anything else except the path to rubymine. But in the new version it does not see my GEM_HOME path, and the gem environment screen shows it pointing to the gem directory in my ruby installation.

I've tried adding a GEM_PATH variable and removing and re-adding the ruby SDK in settings. From the terminal I can output the GEM_HOME variable so the program does see the variables. If I switch my script back to the old version of rubymine it works correctly. Does this new version no longer use GEM_HOME to set the gem path? Thanks